# Receiving as Argument Functions with Constrained Existentials in Haskell

Tags: haskell, constraints, constraint-kinds

I've been playing with some GHC extensions to define a function that can do the following:

```
let a = A :: A  -- Show A
    b = B :: B  -- Show B
  in
    myFunc show a b -- This should return (String, String)
```

`myFunc` should be fully polymorphic in the signature of `show`, so that it can accept `a` and `b` with different types satisfying `Show`.

Here's my attempt with the GHC extensions `RankNTypes`, `ConstraintKinds`, `KindSignatures`:

```
myFunc :: forall (k :: * -> Constraint) a b d. (k a, k b) 
            => (forall c. k c => c -> d) -> a -> b -> (d, d)
```

My main purpose is to understand how these extensions work; but to my eyes, it seems like I'm telling GHC that there's a constraint `k` that some `a` and `b` satisfy, and there's also a function `(forall c. k c => c -> d)` that can take any type `c` satisfying `k` and return a specific `d`, now, under these conditions, I want to apply the function to `a` and `b` to obtain a tuple `(d,d)`

Here's how GHC complains:

```
Could not deduce (k0 a, k0 b)
from the context (k a, k b)
  bound by the type signature for
             myFunc :: (k a, k b) =>
                       (forall c. k c => c -> d) -> a -> b -> (d, d)
  at app/Main.hs:(15,11)-(16,56)
In the ambiguity check for the type signature for ‘myFunc’:
  myFunc :: forall (k :: * -> Constraint) a b d.
            (k a, k b) =>
            (forall c. k c => c -> d) -> a -> b -> (d, d)
To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
In the type signature for ‘myFunc’:
  myFunc :: forall (k :: * -> Constraint) a b d. (k a, k b) =>
            (forall c. k c => c -> d) -> a -> b -> (d, d)

...

Could not deduce (k c)
from the context (k a, k b)
  bound by the type signature for
             myFunc :: (k a, k b) =>
                       (forall c. k c => c -> d) -> a -> b -> (d, d)
  at app/Main.hs:(15,11)-(16,56)
or from (k0 c)
  bound by the type signature for myFunc :: k0 c => c -> d
  at app/Main.hs:(15,11)-(16,56)
In the ambiguity check for the type signature for ‘myFunc’:
  myFunc :: forall (k :: * -> Constraint) a b d.
            (k a, k b) =>
            (forall c. k c => c -> d) -> a -> b -> (d, d)
To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
In the type signature for ‘myFunc’:
  myFunc :: forall (k :: * -> Constraint) a b d. (k a, k b) =>
            (forall c. k c => c -> d) -> a -> b -> (d, d)
app/Main.hs15:40
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I assume you mean polymorphic in the constraints the function argument can have, because otherwise you could simply write `(Show a, Show b) => (forall x. Show x => x -> String) -> a -> b -> (String,String)`? That only requires `RankNTypes`.

Comment: That's true, I want no mention of `Show`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that just passing the function `(forall c . k c => c -> d)` as an argument is not enough for the type-checker to unambiguously determine what `k` really is. Passing the constraint explicitly works and you don't even need the outer `forall` or explicit kinds:

```
import Data.Proxy

myFunc :: (k a, k b) => Proxy k -> (forall c. k c => c -> d) -> a -> b -> (d, d)
myFunc _ f a b = (f a, f b)
```

and then

```
let (c, d) = myFunc (Proxy :: Proxy Show) show a b
```

Comment: I see, thanks a lot; that also explains what GHC means by `To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes`, because I'd normally expect that check to happen on the call site. Of course, thinking of it now, Haskell's type system always tries to catch the problems locally, unlike, say, C++ templates that defer almost everything to the instantiation.

Comment: With GHC8, using `-XAllowAmbiguousTypes` and `-XTypeApplications` offers another solution; the `Proxy` argument vanishes, and you then have `myFunc f a b = (f a, f b)` and `myFunc @Show show a b` at the call site.